# What the purpose of false in element.addEventListener(event, action, false)?

Tags: javascript

From what I've understood reading about **[eventListener on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** the third parameter is options, and across the network, I've seen people doing `(event, action)` and some do `(event, action, false)`.

What I wonder is in the situation where no option are used is fine to go with the first version or there is some downside in performance?

Comment: If the third parameter is `false` then use **bubbling**, if it is `true`, then use **capturing**. The terms bubbling and capturing are explained in the duplicate link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture);
```

The third parameter is a boolean value specifying whether to use event bubbling or event capturing. This parameter is optional.

For more help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: w3schools is a terrible site and you should not link to it to support your answers.